# Fix a Responsive Image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I would like this image to reach only 500px of height for a responsive web site.
The problem is I need several parts like this in a web site that I am making, but can't make it to fix good with every viewport.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}


.bigImages {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

@media (min-width:1400px) {
    .bigImages {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
    }
}





.highlightText3 {
    font-family: $fontLatoHeavy;
    font-size: 8rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 100px 0 100px 0;
    background: rgb(66,
133,
244);;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<h2 class="highlightText3">SERVICES</h2>
<img class="bigImages" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465152251391-e94453ee3f5a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=2f3699fc4dbc682fbecdc4fa4d5f6cad">
```

Comment: This should probably be a background image. Will any other content be on top of it?

Comment: No, no more content on the top of it. Just the title as you can see it, then the image and later some more content...

Comment: Do you need the image to be full-width? Does the image need to display in full, or can it be cropped on some viewports?

Comment: @JeffreyPia yeap the picture need to be full-width, the problem cropping it  is I have 4 pictures like this one and maybe would be hard that all four pictures will be fine, I was reading now about the <picture> element and that would be a fix, but the browser support http://caniuse.com/#search=picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, wrap the image in a container. This way you can constrain the area the image takes up and mask it as needed:

```
<h2 class="highlightText3">SERVICES</h2>
<figure class="image-wrapper">
  <img class="bigImages" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465152251391-e94453ee3f5a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=2f3699fc4dbc682fbecdc4fa4d5f6cad" alt="Surfing a big wave">
</figure>
```

I styled the image-wrapper to have a fixed, 500px height. I then positioned the image absolute so I can push it around and center it. Lastly, I added an aspect-ratio media query to flip how the image is constrained and allow it to scale nicely across all viewport sizes (though the h2 still needs some love on the smaller viewports):

```
.image-wrapper {
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.bigImages {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 4/3) {
  .bigImages {
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
  }
}
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/0o2ykLh7/